# getting next lowest value from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I've got a multi-dimensional array (json encoded, so is that still the right terminology?)

```
{"tasks":[{"task":"first parent task", "sub-tasks":[{"sub-task":"first sub task", "startTime":0, "endTime":30}, {"sub-task":"second sub task", "startTime":65, "endTime":90}]},
{"task":"second parent task", "sub-tasks":[{"sub-task":"task 2 sub task 1", "startTime":35, "endTime":45},{"sub-task":"task 2 sub task 2", "startTime":95, "endTime":100}]}]}
```

I have some javascript to get the current sub-task and I'm trying to get the next sub-task by starttime, but for some reason, i only get the next sub-task in the same parent task. 
So what I'm looking for the output to be is

```
first parent task - first sub task -> nextTask = second parent task - task 2 sub task 1 -> nextTask = first parent task -> second sub task -> nextTask = second parent task - task 2 sub task 2
```

here is the code I currently have, but it only gives me sub tasks from within the same array.

```
for(var r=0;r<tasks.length;r++){
     for (var i = 0; i<tasks[r].sub-tasks.length){
       if(tasks[r].sub-tasks[i].startTime==currenttimer){
         showTask(tasks[r].sub-tasks[i], tasks);
     }
   }
}
function showTask(current, tasks){
     jQuery('div#currentTask').text(current.sub-task);
     var nextStep = current+200; // just to set the next beyond the length of all tasks
     for (var nt=0; nt<tasks.length; nt++){
          for (var nst=0; nst<tasks[nt].sub-tasks.length; nt++){
             if(tasks[nt].sub-tasks[nst].startTime<nextStep 
                && tasks[nt].sub-tasks[nst].startTime>current.startTime){
           jQuery('div#nextTask').text(tasks[nt].sub-tasks[nst].sub-task);
              }
           }
         } 
     }
```

That code returns only first parent task sub-tasks, but I'm not sure why. Is there a better way to do this?

The initial for(var r... statement runs within another loop drawing on a canvas, so I run the loops this way to keep from updating the DOM every second or more.

I would prefer not putting the startTime into a separate array or anything like that as I would need to take that array and refer to the original json anyway and it just seems like a waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically finding the first node that qualifies under your test.  What you need to find is the lowest one that's greater than your current step, so you should just update `nextStep`, store `nt` and `nst` and then run your commands outside the loop.  Like so:

```
function showTask(current, tasks){
 jQuery('div#currentTask').text(current.sub-task);
 var nextStep = current+200; // just to set the next beyond the length of all tasks
 var ntNext, nstNext;
 for (var nt=0; nt<tasks.length; nt++){
      for (var nst=0; nst<tasks[nt].sub-tasks.length; nt++){
         if(tasks[nt].sub-tasks[nst].startTime < nextStep 
            && tasks[nt].sub-tasks[nst].startTime > current.startTime){
              nextStep = tasks[nt].sub-tasks[nst].startTime;
              ntNext   = nt;
              nstNext  = nst;
         }
      }
 } 
 jQuery('div#nextTask').text(tasks[ntNext].sub-tasks[nstNext].sub-task);
}
```

Note that if two start times are the same it will return the first task it finds with that start time.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to this mVChr, been in algo hell.